# grep and awk, combine commands?

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have file that looks like:

```
This is a RESTRICTED site.
All connections are monitored and recorded.
Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized user!
sftp> cd outbox
sftp> ls -ltr
-rw-------   1 0        0            1911 Jun 12 20:40 61N0584832_EDIP000749728818_MFC_20190612203409.txt
-rw-------   1 0        0            1878 Jun 13 06:01 613577165_EDIP000750181517_MFC_20190613055207.txt
```

I want to print only the .txt file names, ideally in one command.

I can do:

```
grep -e '^-' outfile.log > outfile.log2
```

..which gives only the lines that start with '-'.

```
-rw-------   1 0        0            1911 Jun 12 20:40 61N0584832_EDIP000749728818_MFC_20190612203409.txt
-rw-------   1 0        0            1878 Jun 13 06:01 613577165_EDIP000750181517_MFC_20190613055207.txt
```

And then:

```
awk '{print $9}' outfile.log2 > outfile.log3
```

..which gives the desired output:

```
61N0584832_EDIP000749728818_MFC_20190612203409.txt
613577165_EDIP000750181517_MFC_20190613055207.txt
```

And so the question is, can these 2 commands be combined into 1?

Comment: `dos2unix < outfile.log | grep -Po '[^ ]*txt$'`

Comment: Can your file names **ever** contain spaces, eg. `61N0584832 MFC_20190612203409.txt`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use a single `awk`:

```
awk '/^-/{ print $9 }' file > outputfile
```

Or

```
awk '/^-/{ print $9 }' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

It works like this:

- `/^-/` - finds each line starting with `-`
- `{ print $9 }` - prints Field 9 of the matching lines only.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like matching the leading `-` is not really want you want.  If you want to just get the `.txt` files as output, filter on the file name:

```
awk '$9 ~ /\.txt$/{print $9}' input-file
```

Comment: Pluss 1 since you were able to read the request. `I want to print only the .txt file names`

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with `PCRE` enabled (`-P`) flag:

```
grep -oP '^-.* \K.*' outfile.log 
61N0584832_EDIP000749728818_MFC_20190612203409.txt
613577165_EDIP000750181517_MFC_20190613055207.txt
```

`'^-.* \K.*'` : Line starting with `-` till last white space are matched but ignored (anything left of `\K` will be matched and ignored) and matched part right of `\K` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Since he clearly writes `I want to print only the .txt file names`, we should test for txt file and since file name are always the latest column we make it more portable by only test the latest filed line this:

```
awk '$NF ~ /\.txt$/{print $NF}' outfile.log > outfile.log2
61N0584832_EDIP000749728818_MFC_20190612203409.txt
613577165_EDIP000750181517_MFC_20190613055207.txt
```