# awk to update existing file

Tags: unix, awk

As a follow up to this question - [grep and awk, combine commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636453/grep-and-awk-combine-commands)

Using a command such as

```
awk '/^-/{ print $9 }' file > outputfile
```

How can I awk a file and have the output redirected to the same file name?

I tried

```
awk '/^-/ {print $9}' outfile.log >outfile.log
```

..but the resulting outfile.log comes up empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for in-place edit for modifying the same file as mentioned in the duplicate. Your attempt could never work, `awk .. file > file` because the shell processes the re-directions even before running the actual command, so `> file` actually truncates the file, because of an empty re-direction. So the `awk` could never see the value of `$9` in the file.

You probably need `mktemp` which creates a random filename string under a temporary path in your filesystem. You could re-direct the command output to such a file and move it back to the original file

```
awk '/^-/ {print $9}' outfile.log >tmpfile && mv tmpfile outfile.log
```

Using `mktemp` would resolve a potential overwrite/deletion of file if you have a filename `tmpfile` in your current directory.

```
tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
awk '/^-/ {print $9}' outfile.log > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" outfile.log
```

If you use GNU awk, you can write

```
gawk -i inplace '...' file
```

This is [documented in the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace).

Comment: Outstanding, many thanks.  Can you expand on why the use of mktemp would be preferential?

Comment: Using `mv -f` would eliminate the overwrite warning on `outfile.log`.